# PHP Docker image install event extension fails

Tags: php, docker, events

I'm trying to install the `event` extension in **PHP Docker** using `pecl install event-2.5.3`, however, it fails with the error:

> **Error relocating /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/event.so: php_sockets_le_socket: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0**.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.30-cli-alpine3.9
RUN apk --update add \
    autoconf \
    build-base \
    linux-headers \
    libevent-dev \
    openldap-dev \
    imagemagick-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql opcache sockets && \
    docker-php-ext-enable sockets && \
    pecl install event-2.5.3 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable event && \
    docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

This problem has puzzled me for a long time. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not an expert on docker, but your list only shows imagemagick-dev and not imagemagick. I would think both are needed. But this may be unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @fmw42 I can delete the **imagemagick-dev && \\** line, but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem
Going into your image, the ordering of these files determines which are loaded first

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d # ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul  9 20:39 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Jul  9 20:01 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            19 Jul  9 18:39 docker-php-ext-event.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            82 Jul  9 18:39 docker-php-ext-opcache.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            23 Jul  9 18:38 docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            21 Jul  9 18:38 docker-php-ext-sockets.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            20 Jun 28 02:48 docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

`docker-php-ext-enable` allows for a flag to change the `.ini` name, so doing a `docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name zz-event.ini event` has it load in last.
so the correct Dockerfile should be

```
FROM php:7.1.30-cli-alpine3.9

# Packages
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    autoconf \
    build-base \
    linux-headers \
    libevent-dev \
    openldap-dev \
    imagemagick-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets pdo_mysql opcache

RUN docker-php-ext-enable opcache && \
    pecl install event-2.5.3 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name zz-event.ini event


ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
ENV COMPOSER_HOME /tmp
ENV COMPOSER_VERSION 1.5.1


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer \
 && composer --ansi --version --no-interaction

VOLUME /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

CMD [ "php", "./public/server.php" ]
```